# Contador Automático con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

quiero saber cómo puedo hacer que un contador hecho en JavaScript funcione apenas se muestra la sección donde está el mismo, es decir, el contador empieza a andar de 0 a el numero tal que se asigne apenas se carga la página, no cuando se llega a la sección, adjunto código JavaScript:

```
let cont1=document.getElementById('cont1'),
    cont2=document.getElementById('cont2'),
    cont3=document.getElementById('cont3'),
    cont4=document.getElementById('cont4')
let c1=0, c2=0, c3=0, c4=0
tiem=35
let tiempo1= setInterval(() => {
    cont1.textContent=c1+=1

    if(c1===97)
    {
        clearInterval(tiempo1)
    }
}, '${tiem}')
let tiempo2= setInterval(() => {
    cont2.textContent=c2+=1

    if(c2===97)
    {
        clearInterval(tiempo2)
    }
}, '${tiem}')
let tiempo3= setInterval(() => {
    cont3.textContent=c3+=1

    if(c3===12)
    {
        clearInterval(tiempo3)
    }
}, '${tiem}')
let tiempo4= setInterval(() => {
    cont4.textContent=c4+=1

    if(c4===135)
    {
        clearInterval(tiempo4)
    }
}, '${tiem}')
```

Comment: Probaste usando el evento "load"?(document.addEventListener("load", tufuncion))

Comment: Soy bastente nuevo en javascript, entonces no se como deberia poner el evento, me puedes indicar como se haria, por favor?

Comment: Quieres que cada contador empiece en 0 y termine que dependiendo de cada contador se detenga ya sea en 97, 97, 12 y 135?

Comment: Si ese código se ejecuta cuando carga la página claramente va a suceder eso. Necesitas [determinar si el elemento es visible en pantalla](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487073/13419694) luego de de scrollear. Hay [un evento (`scroll`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) que puedes usar para llevar a cabo la verificación cada vez que se scrollee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer un contador solo con CSS

Ejemplo:

```css
@property --contador {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

@property --contarhasta {
  syntax: "<number>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.contador {
  --contarhasta: 0;
  animation: counter 3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  font-size: 4em;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  counter-reset: num var(--contador);
}
.contador-start{
  animation-play-state: running;
}
.contador::before {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --contador: 0;
  }
  to {
    --contador: var(--contarhasta);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contador contador-start" style="--contarhasta:98"></div>

<!-- No inicia, porque no tiene la clase "contador-start" -->
<div class="contador" style="--contarhasta:98"></div>
```

Se crean 2 propiedades personalizadas:

- `--contador`: Es el número que va cambiando, en un momento dado puede ser `12` y luego `22`
- `--contarhasta`: Es el número hasta donde se quiere llegar, siempre es fijo

Además añadí una clase `contador-start`, la cual cuando está presente da inicio al contador (será útil para la próxima parte)

---

Luego para detectar un elemento HTML está en el espacio del viewport, es decir que está visible y no oculto en el scroll, se utiliza [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Demo:

```js
//Este evento se ejecuta cuando se ha cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {

    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting ) {
        entry.target.classList.add('contador-start');
      }
    });
  },{ threshold: 1});

  // threshold = 1 -> La animación comienza cuando el contador se ve complento
  // threshold = 0.5 -> La animación comienza cuando el contador se ve la primera mitad
  // threshold = 0.1 -> La animación comienza cuando el contador se ve un 10%
  //Es decir toma valores entre 0 y 1

  document.querySelectorAll('.contador').forEach(e=> observer.observe(e));

});
```

```css
#divgrande{
  height:120vh;
  background-color:red;
  color:white
}


@property --contador {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

@property --contarhasta {
  syntax: "<number>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.contador {
  --contarhasta: 0;
  animation: counter 3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  font-size: 4em;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  counter-reset: num var(--contador);
}

.contador-start {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.contador::before {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --contador: 0;
  }
  to {
    --contador: var(--contarhasta);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="divgrande">Este div solo es para generar scroll</div>

<div class="contador" style="--contarhasta:98"></div>
```